# How to get white/black effect on sharing buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have one CSS styling that dont know how to fix. I work on personal blog, where author post their images. Hi use black/white effect on images when is not pointer with cursor on it. When close with cursor image get live colours.

[image]
 I want the same style to have on social share buttons too, that is shown in every image.  I searched for that effect in Google, and found this CSS:

```
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

but that make buttons grayed all the time, and i want to change the color in the same way like images do that. You can see for what i talking about [here](http://jitkasimkova.cz/2-2/).

Some tip how to do that? Thanks.

EDIT: This is HTML rendered by executing shortcode:

```
    <div class="entry">
            <div class="nc_socialPanel swp_flatFresh swp_d_fullColor 
swp_i_fullColor swp_o_fullColor scale-100 scale-fullWidth" data-
position="none" data-float="floatNone" data-count="4" data-
floatColor="#ffffff" data-emphasize="0"><div class="nc_tweetContainer 
swp_fb" data-id="3" data-network="facebook"><a rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?
u=http%3A%2F%2Fjitkasimkova.cz%2Ftests%2F" data-
link="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?
u=http%3A%2F%2Fjitkasimkova.cz%2Ftests%2F" class="nc_tweet"><span 
class="swp_count swp_hide"><span class="iconFiller"><span 
class="spaceManWilly"><i class="sw sw-facebook"></i><span class="swp_share"> 
Share</span></span></span></span></a></div><div class="nc_tweetContainer 
twitter" data-id="2" data-network="twitter"><a rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?
original_referer=/&text=tests&url=http://jitkasimkova.cz/tests/" data-
link="https://twitter.com/share?
original_referer=/&text=tests&url=http://jitkasimkova.cz/tests/" 
 class="nc_tweet"><span class="swp_count swp_hide"><span class="iconFiller">
 <span class="spaceManWilly"><i class="sw sw-twitter"></i><span 
 class="swp_share"> Tweet</span></span></span></span></a></div><div 
class="nc_tweetContainer googlePlus" data-id="1" data-network="google_plus">
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?
url=http%3A%2F%2Fjitkasimkova.cz%2Ftests%2F" data-
link="https://plus.google.com/share?
 url=http%3A%2F%2Fjitkasimkova.cz%2Ftests%2F" class="nc_tweet"><span 
class="swp_count swp_hide"><span class="iconFiller"><span 
class="spaceManWilly"><i class="sw sw-google-plus"></i><span 
class="swp_share"> +1</span></span></span></span></a></div><div 
 class="nc_tweetContainer nc_pinterest" data-id="4" data-
network="pinterest"><a rel="nofollow" onClick="var
```

e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e);" class="nc_tweet noPop"> Pin

I get that style by add code from bellow:

```
div.nc_socialPanel .nc_tweetContainer {
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
font-family: Lato;
height: 32px;
margin: 0 5px;
min-width: 34px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
transition: all .1s linear;
border-size: 1px;
 filter: grayscale(100%); // Added this line only.
}
```

But that keep grey all the time. How to make to back the live color when close with cursor?

Comment: can you post the html/css you're using to create the social buttons?

Comment: Its not html, its inserted via ShortCode using Social Warfare plugin for Wordpress. https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-warfare/

Comment: That will render to HTML and CSS on the page - share that.

Comment: Posted HTML in first post.

Comment: Something need to be done on this class, to change the hover when close with cursor. 

`nc_tweetContainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `filter: grayscale` while in `:hover` state

I don't know what selector you're using but it would be the same one you're using to apply the `greyscale filter` with the exception that you would add `:hover` to it.

The **images** in your example also make use of some sort of `transition` to make the **move between grey-scale and full color smooth**.

```css
.class:hover {filter:greyscale(0)}
```

Comment: Your answer was most usefull then others. Help me to resolve myself the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using the grayscale filter you mentioned. You just need to get rid of the filter when hovered.

```css
.nc_tweetContainer {
  transition: filter 0.25s;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.nc_tweetContainer:hover{
  transition: filter 0.25s;
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="nc_tweetContainer" src="http://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="placecage">
```

Comment: Your suggestion is good, but how to integrate into CSS? I have posted HTML before in first post.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I believe you can change my `img` selectors into `.nc_tweetContainer` and it should work.

Comment: I cant change code, because is generated by shortcode.

Comment: You will only need to modify CSS code, or add an external stylesheet to your document with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

This is Fully Working CSS that resolve my issue.

```
.eg-thegrid-gallery-bnw-element-15 {
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.eg-thegrid-gallery-bnw-element-15:hover {
 filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Thanks for all for helping me to resolve this. :)